# How to copy files from one AWS account to Another AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to move files from client S3 Buckets to our S3 Buckets. I tried few things:

1. Using S3 browser copy and paste
2. AWS CLI sync/cp but I got stuck how to pass access key and access id of source/destination location

Would you please give me some pointers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

**Pull files**

Setup a bucket policy in your source granting read access to the user/role in the destination account.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::DEST_ACCOUNT:user/DestinationAccountUserName"
        },
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you can run `aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://dest-bucket` with a user in the destination account.

**Push files**

Setup a bucket policy in your destination granting write access to the user/role in the source account.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
         ],
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::SOURCE_ACCOUNT:user/SourceAccountUserName"
        },
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::dest-bucket"
         ],
         "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
               "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you can run `aws s3 sync --acl bucket-owner-full-control s3://source-bucket s3://dest-bucket` with a user in the source account. **IMPORTANT** If you don't set the ACL, the bucket owner in the destination account won't be able to access the objects, that's why we enforce the ACL in the `"Condition"`.

Here's an AWS post about this: https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: Alternatively, have the destination account _pull_ from the source account. This avoids the ACL problems. The source bucket would need a bucket policy granting permission for the destination account to read the content.

Comment: John Rotenstein's comment is important. If you copy using source credentials to the destination bucket, the ownership of the files stay with the source credentials. This can cause needless problems. Always use the credentials for the destination account to copy from a bucket in one account to a bucket in a different account.

Comment: That's right, but that's why I added the --acl flag, it prevents exactly that.

Comment: @charli - That is the problem. The owner stays the same which can be a big problem later on. The key is to use credentials for the destination account and copy from the source bucket - not the other way around.

Comment: Updated answer with 2 possible options. IMHO, both approaches are valid if we use the ACL when pushing objects. I think the approach depends on the agreement between parts, and not necessarily technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://blog.vizuri.com/how-to-copy-or-move-objects-from-one-s3-bucket-to-another-between-aws-accounts-part-1) shows a few options...

> - AWS S3 console - suitable when dealing with a limited number of
>     objects, or transferring within the same AWS account.
> - AWS command line
>     interface (cli) - EC2 command line tool.
> - AWS S3 SDK -  If you are
>     ready to do some coding and write your own script.
> - s3cmd from
>     s3tools.org - command line tool written in Python. Check out Alfie La
>     Peter's article on this.
> - S3 Browser - Windows only.
> - CloudBerry S3
>     Explorer - Windows only, and at a price.
> - Bucket Explorer - Supports
>     Windows, Mac and Linux (at a price).
> - CloudBuddy - MS Office plug-in.
> - S3Fox - Firefox add-on.

...and it also gives details on [how to migrate using AWS CLI](https://blog.vizuri.com/how-to-copy/move-objects-from-one-s3-bucket-to-another-between-aws-accounts). Macro steps:

> - Create/Identify Buckets
> - Create IAM user account
> - Setup user credentials
> - Create a User Policy
> - Create Bucket Policy
> - Verify AWS S3 CLI availability on EC2 instance
> - Configure S3 CLI credentials
> - Finally copy and move some S3 objects